# CSS selector isn't applying to an inner element in Bulma Hero

Tags: html, css, bulma

So I'm trying to customize the Hero component from Bulma. When I try to target a CSS selector at an element inside of it, it doesn't seem to be applying. When testing, I can set the `font-size` to 100pt and `color: red` with no effect. Here's my work:

**index.css**

```
#headline-container {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #00aff4;
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgb(60, 197, 255) 0%, rgb(0, 181, 255) 100%);
};

#titley {
    font-size: 28pt;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: red;
    font-family: "Roboto Condensed", Arial Narrow, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align: right;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.1/css/bulma.css" integrity="sha256-zKA1Bf41O96+gJSlkn/Bh2HATW/OhwkApPlYTp3B5O8=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="hero is-large is-info" id="headline-container">
    <div class="hero-body">
      <div class="level">
        <div class="level-left">
          <div class="level-item">
            <div id="titley">Here's my big fancy headline.</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The `#titley` tag on the inner `div` has no effect, but that's not just with an ID. I've tried many different selectors, so at this point I'm wondering if there's some glaring/obvious mistake I've been making.

Chrome developer tools doesn't show any information about my `#titley` style when I select the element.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a semicolon when closing `#headline-container`.
Try this CSS:

```
#headline-container {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #00aff4;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgb(60, 197, 255) 0%, rgb(0, 181, 255) 100%);
}

#titley {
  font-size: 28pt;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: red;
  font-family: "Roboto Condensed", Arial Narrow, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Also, I suggest using a `container` class instead of a `level` class.
A level class goes best with a `nav` element, not a `div` element.

Comment: Thanks, I have a plugin to convert CSS-in-JS to CSS, and I guess I missed the semicolon. Feeling silly.

Comment: I'm looking for the best way to show a very large image on the right side of the Hero and figured a level might be a good way to do it. Columns didn't pan out so well

Comment: @patrickjm Check out one of my templates which does a similar job: https://aldi.github.io/awesome-bulma-templates/templates/cv.html .                      You can use two `divs` with classes `tile is-6`

Answer (score 0):

There's a semicolon behind the curly brackets, can't yet find anything else what's wrong.
But as Google isn't displaying it, that should be it.